# Running pygame instantly closes. Something is wrong with my player update function

Tags: python, function, class, pygame

When I run my code, it instantly opens then closes the pygame window, however when I delete the `player.update()` code it works. I can't seem to find what is wrong with the update function in my player class

```
"""Dot Game"""
```

```
#Imports
import pygame, sys
from game import Game

g = Game()

while g.running:
    g.curr_menu.display_menu()
    g.game_loop()

#Constants
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720
TITLE = "Dot."

background = pygame.image.load('BG.png')
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

#pygame initialization
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
#fps
FPS = 60
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()

#colors
bgc = (247, 226, 222)
pc = (152, 193, 217)
pc2 = (61, 90, 128) #dark
ec = (119, 2, 26) #dark
ec2 = (220, 66, 73)

#accel
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
accel_x = 0
accel_y = 0
max_speed = 10

display_width, display_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
x = display_width * 0.45
y = display_height * 0.8

#Player Class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.radius = 32
        self.width = 2
        self.color = pc
        self.color2 = pc2
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.up_pressed = False
        self.down_pressed = False
        self.a_pressed = False
        self.d_pressed = False
        self.w_pressed = False
        self.s_pressed = False
        self.attack_animation = False
        self.sprites = []
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('0000.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('0001.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('0002.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('0003.png'))
        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = [x,y]

        self.acceleration = 0.4
        self.friction = 0.92 # = 1  is no friction

    def attack(self):
        self.attack_animation = True


    def update(self,speed):
        
        if self.attack_animation == True:
            self.current_sprite += speed
            if int(self.current_sprite) >= len(self.sprites):
                self.current_sprite = 1
                self.attack_animation = False
        self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)] 

        if self.left_pressed:
            if self.velX > -max_speed:
                self.velX -= self.acceleration
        if self.right_pressed:
            if self.velX < max_speed:
                self.velX += self.acceleration
        if self.up_pressed:
            if self.velY > -max_speed:
                self.velY -= self.acceleration
        if self.down_pressed :
            if self.velY < max_speed:
                self.velY += self.acceleration
        
        self.x += self.velX
        self.y += self.velY
        self.velX *= self.friction
        self.velY *= self.friction

        player.attack()

            
           
        


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.radius = 32
        self.color = ec
        self.color2 = ec2
        self.vel = 3
        self.hitbox = (self.x -20, self.y -20, 40, 40)
        self.points = [(self.x -10, self.y +14), (self.x, self.y -6), (self.x +10, self.y +14)]
        self.points2 = [(self.x -20, self.y +20), (self.x, self.y -20), (self.x +20, self.y +20)] # L U R

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.polygon(win, self.color, self.points2)
        pygame.draw.polygon(win, self.color2, self.points)
        self.hitbox = (self.x -20, self.y -20, 40, 40)
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, ec2, self.hitbox, 2)






#Player Initialization
moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
enemy = Enemy(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
moving_sprites.add(player)



#Main Loop
collide = False
while not collide:
    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.left_pressed = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.right_pressed = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.up_pressed = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.down_pressed = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.left_pressed = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.right_pressed = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.up_pressed = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.down_pressed = False
    
    x_change += accel_x  # Accelerate.
    if abs(x_change) >= max_speed:  # If max_speed is exceeded.
        # Normalize the x_change and multiply it with the max_speed.
        x_change = x_change/abs(x_change) * max_speed

    y_change += accel_y  # Accelerate.
    if abs(y_change) >= max_speed:  # If max_speed is exceeded.
        # Normalize the x_change and multiply it with the max_speed.
        y_change = y_change/abs(y_change) * max_speed

    #Draw
    win.blit(background,(0,0))
    enemy.draw(win)
    moving_sprites.draw(win)
    

    #update
    
    #player.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    moving_sprites.update(0.12)
    fpsclock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `player.update()` in a `try/except` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update` method has a *speed* argument.

> ```py
> def update(self,speed):
> ```

Therefore you need to pass the speed to the `update` method:

<s>`player.update()`</s>

```py
speed = 1 # just for example
player.update(speed)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mixed it up with the call to `player.attack()` from inside `update`.  That's where the bug is.  The call you fixed is correct.